# Rails routes url edit_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm having a problem with my routes:

```
No route matches events/edit_national_event
```

The generated URL : 
    http://localhost:3000/events/edit_national_event.:id

I need :
    http://localhost:3000/events/:id/edit_national_event

it works with destroy but not with edit. What is wrong with my code ?

routes :

```
 resources :events, only: [:index, :destroy] do
    collection do
      get :new_national_event
      get :new_local_event
      post :create_national_event
      post :create_local_event
    end
    member do
      get :edit_national_event
      get :edit_local_event
      put :update_national_event
      put :update_local_event
    end
  end
```

Event-controllor :

```
def edit_national_event
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

view :

```
@group_events.each do |event|
  tr
    td
      =event.title
    td
      =link_to edit_national_event_event_path(event)
      =link_to event_path(event), method: :delete
```

When I'm doing rake routes :

```
new_national_event_events GET    /events/new_national_event(.:format)                                   events#new_national_event
new_local_event_events GET    /events/new_local_event(.:format)                                      events#new_local_event
create_national_event_events POST   /events/create_national_event(.:format)                                events#create_national_event
create_local_event_events POST   /events/create_local_event(.:format)                                   events#create_local_event
edit_national_event_event GET    /events/:id/edit_national_event(.:format)                              events#edit_national_event
edit_local_event_event GET    /events/:id/edit_local_event(.:format)                                 events#edit_local_event
update_national_event_event PUT    /events/:id/update_national_event(.:format)                            events#update_national_event
update_local_event_event PUT    /events/:id/update_local_event(.:format)                               events#update_local_event
events GET    /events(.:format)                                                      events#index
event DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                                                  events#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the `rake routes` output, the route you're looking for is shown as `/events/:id/edit_national_event(.:format)`. Which means it's expecting an event ID in the URL. You're not providing one, which is why it doesn't match.

The reason it's expecting an ID is that you define the route in the `member` block, rather than the `collection` one. If you don't want there to be an ID in the URL, move the route to the `collection` block. If you do want an ID, make sure to include it when linking to that action.